# How change all uppercase words to lowercase, but exclude string literals in Vim

Tags: regex, vim

I got rather long sql script where all keyword are uppercase. I want to change them to lowercase, but preserve exact values of string literals and my own identifers.
For example, in this text:

```
KEYWORD BEFORE 'SOME STRING LITERAL' KEYWORD AFTER
mixedCaseValue  
MY_OWN_VARAIBLE
UGLY APPERCASE KEYWORDS, other text
```

I want only 'KEYWORD BEFORE', 'KEYWORD AFTER' and last 'UGLY UPPERCASE KEYWORDS' to be lowercase and all other left intact.
If I use something like this `:%s/\<\u\+\>/\L&/g`, text inside quotes on the first line is also affected.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Does this help, I'm not so sure what you need here - http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Switching_case_of_characters

Comment: Could you please elaborate on a stricter syntactic definition of a string literal in the programming language you use?  Can those single-quoted string literals span over multiple lines?  Is there a syntax for escaping single quotes inside string literals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that string literals do not span over multiple lines, and that there is
no syntax for escaping single quotes inside string literals, I would use the
following substitution command.

```
:%s/\%(^\%([^']*'[^']*'\)*\)\@<=[^']\+/\=substitute(submatch(0),'\<\u\+\>','\L&','g')/g
```

Comment: It almost works - if you run it for my example, it will also change `mixedCaseValue` and `MY_OWN_VARAIBLE`. But now I know in which direction to go. Thanks!

Comment: @east825:  I missed that you would like to lowercase not everything outside of string literals, but only all-uppercase words.  The command I have proposed can be changed to do that; please, see the update of the answer.

Comment: WOW! That's huge! And it seems to work exactly as I wanted (at least at first glance). I think You are the winner. Now I need to spend some time digging in Vim help to understand what it does)

Answer (score 2):

One way:

```
:%v/'/s/\(^\|\s\)\@<=\u\+\(\s\|,\)\@=/\L&/g
```

Explanation:

```
%                      # Range: All file.
v/pattern/command      # Apply command to all lines that doesn't match pattern
'                      # The pattern, so apply substitution to lines that doesn't have it.
s/string/replacement/  # Replacement command.
\(^\|\s\)\@<=          # Zero-width preceding match: Beginning of line or a space.
\u\+                   # One or more alphabetic uppercase letters.
\(\s\|,\)\@=           # Zero-width positive match: Space or comma.
\L&                    # Lowercase the string matched
/g                     # Apply globally: Many times for each line.
```

Result:

```
'SOME STRING LITERAL'  
mixedCaseValue  
MY_OWN_VARAIBLE
ugly appercase keywords, other text
```

Comment: Nice solution! I did't know about '\@<=' and '\@=' before. Thought I think that it'll be even better without v/ at beginning. Because of it this pattern doesn't match upperace keyword on the same lines with string literals (I didn't show such case in example). And with at least $ inside second braces to match keywords at the end of line.

Comment: @east825: Yes. You are right. It's a specific solution for your example, but could fail with many other cases. Complete your example with other possibilities and more users will give a better approach.

Comment: Sorry, my bad - without `v/` it will also match uppercase words inside quotes ('STRING' in example).

Answer (score 1):

My inner vim-loving soul cringes to write these, but...

If this is something you don't have to do frequently, you might just brute-force it by appending the `c` flag onto your substitution command to prompt for confirmation of each change; you should be able to blow through a lot of script quickly, if you can put up with the tedium.  It might be faster this way (in the short term) than by spending time crafting a good substitution command.

Alternatively, if there are only a handful of string literals that need to not be touched, change those to some other string so the global substitution doesn't change them, do the global substitution, and then change them back.  Also gross but effective.

Ugh, I feel dirty.

Comment: Actually I did so already) I just was wondering may be someone know some nice pattern, that can do such substitution automatically.