# How to change cases from upper to lower except character string in FORTRAN

Tags: vim, fortran

I'm handling huge legacy code and considering Vim as code formatter.

Can I achieve the following:

1. If possible, I want to change the whole code to lower case except character string.
2. Also, when textwidth is set to 80, gq command separate long lines.
   In this case, how can I add continuation character & end of line automatically?

If there's a way, please let me know..

Comment: I don't think a simple substitution will take you there, as you have to deal with continuation lines to be correct. I know that syntax highlighting in `vim` is able to skip over unwanted matches within regions (it's even able to correctly highlight strings like `"\""', switch on spell checking in string literals, etc.), so there seems to be enough machinery in place to solve your problem. It might be hard to exploit that machinery, though (I can't think of a good way quickly :-( ).

Answer (score 3):

You can have a look at this: [How change all uppercase words to lowercase, but exclude string literals in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753784/how-change-all-uppercase-words-to-lowercase-but-exclude-string-literals-in-vim)

The suggested solution is:

```
:%s/\%(^\%([^']*'[^']*'\)*\)\@<=[^']\+/\=substitute(submatch(0),'\<\u\+\>','\L&','g')/g
```

Another useful link:
http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/8255-vim-tips-the-basics-of-search-and-replace

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just visited recommended pages and what I really needed is

:%s/\%(^\%([^']*'[^']*'\)*\)\@<=[^']\+/\L&/g

Answer (score 2):

The [NAG Fortran Compiler](http://www.nag.co.uk/nagware/NP/NP_desc.asp) comes with an integrated pretty printer:

```
> cat foo.f90 && nagfor =polish -idcase=L -kwcase=L -margin=0 -noblank_line_after_decls -width=80 foo.f90 && cat foo.f90_pol
PROGRAM P
  INTEGER :: I
  INTEGER :: THIS_INTEGER_VARIABLE_HAS_A_REALLY_LONG_NAME
  PRINT *, 'IS THIS THING ON?'
  I = THIS_INTEGER_VARIABLE_HAS_A_REALLY_LONG_NAME * THIS_INTEGER_VARIABLE_HAS_A_REALLY_LONG_NAME
END PROGRAM P
NAG Fortran Polisher Release 6.0(Hibiya) Build 1037
[NAG Fortran Polisher normal termination]
program p
  integer :: i
  integer :: this_integer_variable_has_a_really_long_name
  print *, 'IS THIS THING ON?'
  i = this_integer_variable_has_a_really_long_name* &
    this_integer_variable_has_a_really_long_name
end program p
```

(Disclosure: I work for NAG.)

Comment: Nice feature. I'd just wish fortran wouldn't need this stuff, the line length limit & upper case in legacy code drives me nuts...